# maximum value of sum of autocorrelation coefficients

Tags: autocorrelation

Let $x_t$  be a stationary process, such that autocorrelation dies down (is insignificant) after 3 lags.
Let correlation at lag i be denoted by $\rho_i $

Let $y_t$ be given by
$$y_t = \sum_{t-10}^t x_i $$

$$=> \sigma^2_y = \sigma^2(\sum_{t-10}^t x_i)  \approx   \sigma^2_x (10  +  2 * ( 9\rho_1 + 8 \rho_2 + 7 \rho_3 ))$$

Since $\sigma^2_y >0$, this gives a lower limit on $( 0.9\rho_1 +  0.8\rho_2 + 0.7\rho_3 ) $ of $-0.5$.

Is there a theoretical upper limit on $( 0.9\rho_1 +  0.8\rho_2 + 0.7\rho_3 )$ also?